# Buildroot > 2019.2: How to fix qt5virtualkeyboard install fail?

Tags: qt, embedded, embedded-linux, buildroot

So I'm trying to upgrade an old buildroot system, from 2018.08.x to the latest release. The issue is that upgrading from 2019.2.x to 2019.5.x or 2019.8.x generates an error while installing qt5virtualkeyboard 5.12.2.

**Note**: after revision 2019.2.x the Qt kits are updated from 5.11 to 5.12.

I've checked the package install.mk but there are no changes in the related lines:

```
ifdef QT5VIRTUALKEYBOARD_3RDPARTY_PARTS
define QT5VIRTUALKEYBOARD_INSTALL_TARGET_3RDPARTY_PARTS
        cp -dpfr $(STAGING_DIR)/usr/qtvirtualkeyboard $(TARGET_DIR)/usr
endef
endif
```

and I've already tested that cleaning the `qt5virtualkeyboard->language layouts` and the `qt5virtualkeyboard->handwriting` resolve the issue.

Here's the `make` output from revision 2019.5.x:

```
qt5virtualkeyboard 5.12.2 Installing to target
mkdir -p /home/fg/work/acto/buildroot/output/target/usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforminputcontexts
cp -dpfr /home/fg/work/acto/buildroot/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libqtvirtualkeyboardplugin.so /home/fg/work/acto/buildroot/output/target/usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforminputcontexts
cp -dpf /home/fg/work/acto/buildroot/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib/libQt5VirtualKeyboard*.so.* /home/fg/work/acto/buildroot/output/target/usr/lib
mkdir -p /home/fg/work/acto/buildroot/output/target/usr/qml/QtQuick
cp -dpfr /home/fg/work/acto/buildroot/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/qml/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard /home/fg/work/acto/buildroot/output/target/usr/qml/QtQuick/
cp -dpfr /home/fg/work/acto/buildroot/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/qtvirtualkeyboard /home/fg/work/acto/buildroot/output/target/usr
cp: cannot stat '/home/fg/work/acto/buildroot/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/qtvirtualkeyboard': No such file or directory
package/pkg-generic.mk:331: recipe for target '/home/fg/work/acto/buildroot/output/build/qt5virtualkeyboard-5.12.2/.stamp_target_installed' failed
make: *** [/home/fg/work/acto/buildroot/output/build/qt5virtualkeyboard-5.12.2/.stamp_target_installed] Error 1
```

At the moment I disabled the virtual keyboard configs to work on the system. But I would like to go deeper: I would like to understand if, during the update process, something went wrong, if I need to add some new dependencies packages or if this might be a package installation error.

Comment: First of all, bug reports should be sent to the mailing list, not to stackoverflow. That said: do you have the zh_CN layout enabled (but not "all")? I see that something has changed there, and that the pinyin plugin no longer installs a dictionary in the qtvirtualkeyboard directory.

Comment: I had the **all** layout and did not work. Without any layout it worked properly.

Comment: Weird. With the "all" layout, it triggers openwnn and that definitely installs something in the data directory...

Comment: Could you post the output of the installation to staging which comes a bit higher? There should be something there about openwnn, and there should be something there about installing to `/home/fg/work/acto/buildroot/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/.../qtvirtualkeyboard`. Maybe the data path is different from what we expect.